# Exclude NuGet package based on custom property value in MSBuild file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

I'm building a C# solution that has multiple projects and a `Directory.Build.props` file at its root with the following content:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsRelevantProject>false</IsRelevantProject>
    <IsRelevantProject Condition="$(MSBuildProjectName.StartsWith('Relevant')) == true">true</IsRelevantProject>
    <LangVersion Condition="'$(IsRelevantProject)' == 'false'">8</LangVersion>
    <LangVersion Condition="'$(IsRelevantProject)' == 'true'">7.3</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Condition="'$(IsRelevantProject)' == 'false'" Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" Version="16.5.124-alpha" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm trying to include the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers` NuGet package only in projects that have the `IsRelevantProject` property set to false but it seems that the condition is getting ignored as all project have the package included. The condition works fine on `LangVersion`, I've verified that projects are compiled with the expected `/langversion` csc argument.

I've tried using a built-in property value (`Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"`) and it it seemed to work fine. The NuGet package would only get included when the config was set to debug. Is it not possible to use a custom property or include a package in only certain projects based on project name or when it's defined in a shared MSBuild file?

Comment: To continue investigation set build output logging to most detailed and stare at the output... That's pain, but at least may get you info what actually happens. You may want to do that on minimal sample project, or at least disable parallel build while looking at detailed logs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue was specific to using an Analyzer package. They get applied to the project they're installed on and all dependent projects. After adding `PrivateAssets="all"` to `PackageReference`, it started working as expected.